# How to make a true recursion in this case?

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, templating

So i want to program JS to make me a layout like this:

```
<div class="collection">
  <div class="color"></div>
  <div class="color"></div>
  <div class="color"></div>
</div>
```

what i already did is this

```
var collections = [
  { collection: ["#000", "#222", "#333"] }
]
function saveColors(){
  var collection = [];
  var colorBlocks = document.getElementsByClassName("colored"),
      colSpace = document.getElementById("collection-space"),
      firstColor = document.getElementById("first");

  var color1 = colorBlocks[0].textContent,
      color2 = colorBlocks[1].textContent,
      color3 = colorBlocks[2].textContent;

  if(firstColor.dataset.first != "true"){
    collections.push({collection: [color1, color2, color3]});
    console.log(collections);
    var collectionBlock = document.createElement('div');
    collectionBlock.className = "collection";
    var color = document.createElement('div');
    color.className = "color";

    for(i=0;i<collections.length;i++){
      colSpace.appendChild(collectionBlock);
      for(x=0;x<collections[i].collection.length;x++){
        var collection = document.getElementsByClassName("collection");
        collection[i].appendChild(color);
      }
    }

  }
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jzheh2cf/
So there is a thing that you have to know. So i have a random color generator, and it generates a random colors for 3 blocks in my HTML layout. And that is not the main thing, that is just an information. I just want to explain that in this first lines of code, i am making an object/array of collections. Then i am taking an innerHTML of my color blocks than contain a hex color code. Then i am taking a space where this layout should be placed (`colSpace = document.geti("collection-space")`). And when i am generating a layout, i want to have 3 colors in one collection, as in example, but I always get only one. What do i have to change in `collection[i].appendChild(color)` or anywhere else?

Comment: your question is very confusing, please make a fiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/ and what you are trying to do

Comment: i don't see what has your question got to do with "recursion"

Comment: @SumamaWaheed When i put it inside for some reason it doesnt see my functions from JavaScript. But they are the main thing. Okey, whatever, check it: https://jsfiddle.net/jzheh2cf/

Comment: @SumamaWaheed okey functions work now, check that https://jsfiddle.net/jzheh2cf/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey, I already solved a problem. I rewrote the whole `for` thing.
So if you are a guy that is looking for an answer, here is my final JS code:

```
var collections = [
  { collection: ["#000", "#222", "#333"] }
]
function saveColors(){
  var colorBlocks = document.getElementsByClassName("colored"),
      colSpace = document.getElementById("collection-space"),
      firstColor = document.getElementById("first");

  var color1 = colorBlocks[0].textContent,
      color2 = colorBlocks[1].textContent,
      color3 = colorBlocks[2].textContent;

  if(firstColor.dataset.first != "true"){
    collections.push({collection: [color1, color2, color3]});
    console.log(collections);

    var collectionBlock = document.createElement('div');
    collectionBlock.className = "collection";

    var color = document.createElement('div');
    color.className = "color";
    color.setAttribute("onclick", "displayCopyPaste(this)");

    var color2 = document.createElement('div');
    color2.className = "color";
    color2.setAttribute("onclick", "displayCopyPaste(this)");

    var color3 = document.createElement('div');
    color3.className = "color";
    color3.setAttribute("onclick", "displayCopyPaste(this)");

    for(i=0; i < collections.length; i++ ){
      colSpace.appendChild(collectionBlock);
      //cN = colorName
      for(cN = 0; cN < collections[i].collection.length; cN++){
        color.innerHTML = collections[i].collection[0];
        color.style.backgroundColor = collections[i].collection[0];

        color2.innerHTML = collections[i].collection[1];
        color2.style.backgroundColor = collections[i].collection[1];

        color3.innerHTML = collections[i].collection[2];
        color3.style.backgroundColor = collections[i].collection[2];
      }
      collectionBlock.appendChild(color);
      collectionBlock.appendChild(color2);
      collectionBlock.appendChild(color3);
    }
  }
}
```

Here you go guys.